# testdisk won't show "undelete" option for my Linux Mint partition

Tags: data-recovery, mint

I was testing Encfs gnome, when the folder I tried to encrypt didn't really encrypt (only copied to enfcs manager), so I deleted the folder form enfcs manager then when I checked my documents folder where the folder was stored I saw that it was gone, so I tried to use testdisk, but the deleted files wouldn't show. Then I discovered that I need to go in to "undelete" I couldn't see it as an option on my partition where Linux Mint is installed and where the folder was deleted, only on the MS Data partition. I am running a dual boot with Windows to play some Steam games, but Linux Mint is my main OS. I also have my LM home folder encrypted if that is causing any issues.

"undelete" not being visible:

[image: Image of "undelete" not being visible]

Comment: Mint is off topic here.

Comment: Only Ubuntu and [official flavors of Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Linux Mint forum. (*One advantage of Ubuntu is it's many support options, you opted for Linux Mint so take advantage of its support options, or SE Unix & Linux* found in the on-topic link)